# What can i say about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n\int_0^\pi 2\sin(mx)\cos(nx)\mathrm dx$ ??

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation

I'm trying to solve the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n\underbrace{\int_0^\pi  2\sin(mx)\cos(nx)\mathrm dx}_{\kappa_{n,m}}$$
where for $\kappa_{n,m}$ I did:
\begin{align*}
\kappa_{n,m}&=\int_0^\pi\left\{\sin\left[(n+m)x\right]-\sin\left[(n-m)x\right]\right\}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{\cos\left[(n-m)\pi\right]}{n-m}-\frac{\cos\left[(n+m)\pi\right]}{n+m}-\frac1{n-m}+\frac1{n+m}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{n-m}-\frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n+m}-\frac{2m}{n^2-m^2}\\
&=\frac{2m}{n^2-m^2}\big((-1)^{n-m}-1\big).
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n\kappa_{n,m}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n\frac{2m}{n^2-m^2}\big((-1)^{n-m}-1\big)
\end{align*}
What I'm able to say from this last point is that the sum above is equal to $\displaystyle i\pi 
p^m$ when $n=m$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Also, it is equal to zero for the case where $n-m$ is an even number for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. I would like to shed some light on this last step in particular.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

There is an explicit expression for the infinite summation but it involves several special functions
$$F(p,m)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n\frac{2m}{n^2-m^2}\big((-1)^{n-m}-1\big)
=p \Big[\Phi (p,1,1+m)-\Phi (p,1,1-m)\Big]+$$ $$\frac{(-1)^m }{m^2-1}p\Big[(m+1) \, _2F_1(1,1-m;2-m;-p)+(m-1) \, _2F_1(1,1+m;2+m;-p)\Big]$$ where, beside the gaussian hypergeometric function appears the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.

The contour plots of $\Re [F(p,m)]$ and $\Im [F(p,m)]$ are very interesting to look at; may be, they could give you some ideas.

Comment: Hello, mr. Claude! Nice and difficult closed form for this sum. Now I can conclude that maybe I used a complicated approach, as we arrived at a sum with a complicated closed form.

Comment: @lpb. Your approach is fine. The problem is the summation.